# YUI Compressor with .NET website project

Tags: c#, .net, yui, yui-compressor

I see several examples of how to use the YUI Compressor to minify js and css files on a <s>"web application"</s> "website" project. I want to know how it can be used on a <s>"website"</s> "web application" project on .NET. The main concern is that website projects doesn't seem to support configuration of post build instructions.

Any help appreciated.

**EDIT:**
In my initial version, I had interchanged web application for website. I actually have a website application, and need to know how I can integrate YUI Compressor with it.

Comment: each .proj-file supports these build-events ... it must be UI which hides the boxes, but if you'd opened the .proj-file you'd find these elements :)

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET web applications do support post build events. Go to web applications settings page.

[image]

Click on the Build Events button and this window will open.

[image]

Click on the "Edit Post Build" button to open the post build editor.

Comment: You are right, my question is wrong. I actually have a website project, and those types do not support post build instructions. :-)